# Can a vector be defined by invariance of some algebraic operation to translations rather than rotations?

Tags: vectors

Every physics book I've come across defines a vector as an n-tuple of numbers that can be combined via an inner product that's invariant to rotations.

Is it possible to instead define a vector via an algebraic operation that's invariant to translations, or is there something unique about the invariance of an algebraic operation to rotations when defining a vector?

Comment: As a side note, while fixed vectors are not invariant under such transformations, free vectors are. Most quantities in physics are described by free vectors. While shifting the coordinate system will change such vectors, shifting the vectors themselves will not affect them.

Answer (score 3):

I've never understood why physicists are so insistent about defining vectors that weird way instead of just taking a mathematical vector space and equipping it with the normal dot product, but yes, there *is* something special about rotations (combined with reflections).

They are are *orthogonal matrices*, meaning that $M M^T = M^T M = \mathbf{1}$ for every rotation matrix. For Euclidean vectors, the inner product is just the dot product $\langle x , x \rangle = x^T x$, and therefore, under rotation, we have $\langle Mx,Mx\rangle = (Mx)^TMx = x^TM^TMx = x^Tx$, so the matrices leaving this product invariant are precisely the orthogonal matrices.

More generally, an inner product is given by $\langle x ,x \rangle = x^T G x$ with G any symmetric non-degenerate matrix, i.e. $G = G^T$ and $G$ has no zero eigenvalues. Then, the orthogonal matrices preserve the product only if they commute with $G$, i.e. if $[G,M] = 0$. This is not necessarily given, and in fact only true when $G = \pm \mathbf{1}$, so the physicist's definition of a vector is somewhat weird, since vector spaces need not carry a specific inner product at all. What the physicist's definition fixes is *not* only the vector space structure, but also that it is Euclidean space, i.e. equipped with the normal dot product.

Now, translations are not matrices, since every matrix represents a linear map, which must map the zero vector to the zero vector, so you would demand that $\langle x + a , x + a \rangle = \langle x ,x \rangle$ for the vectors $a$ by which you could translate, and this yields

$$ \langle x + a, x + a \rangle = \langle x,x\rangle + 2 \langle x,a\rangle + \langle a,a\rangle$$

Which is obviously untrue if $x$ and $a$ are orthogonal and $a$ is non-zero, so there is no inner product that could ever be invariant under translation. Note that there is another notion of translation, that you would translate on *spacetime* and the inner product of vectors in the tangent space would not change when translated along the path of translation, but that's wholly another story, and certainly unrelated to *defining* the tangent spaces in the first place.

Comment: +1 Great account but a nitpick is that you can represent translations by homogeneous linear maps (matrices) acting on homogeneous(projective) co-ordinates; for example, the Euclidean group $\mathbb{E}(2)$ is the set of all matrices of the form $\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&-i\,(x-i\,y)\frac{e^{i\,\phi}-1}{\phi}\\0&e^{i\,\phi}\\\end{array}\right)$ which encode translations through the vector $(x,y)$ and rotations through angle $\phi$ and the matrices act on a "vector" of the form $(z,e^{i\,\phi})$ which encodes an object at position $z=x+i y$ in the Argand plane with orientation $\phi$.